dconf-CRITICAL: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly
I have set up an NIS server and NIS client. I successfully logged in to the NIS client using VNC by NIS users.
But when I try to use some software like HFSS, the software will crash and output the message "Recurise lock!" then I get the error from logs:
Sender:gnome-session-b
Message:conf-CRITICAL: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
And I try the 'env | grep XDG_RUNTIME_DIR' and it points to /run/user/0 .
I thought this would be some mistakes from here.
I am using Rocky Linux 8.10
I set the NIS by the following setenter image description here
authselect enable-feature with-mkhomedir
setsebool -P nis_enabled on
I don't know how to solve this problem and make the software work.
The NIS user's environment seems to point to the root uses folder.

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.
